# How to store values globally, permantly?

Tags: php, session, cookies, global-variables, counter

I want to store some counter and want to increment as desired.
This counters are not related to any client, so i cant use session or cookies.
I tried $GLOBALS but, its not what i want.

I want something like, let say i have 3 php files, each will do some counter manuplation.

**init.php**

```
$_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] = 0;
```

**file1.php**

```
$_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] = $_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] + 7;
```

**file2.php**

```
$_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] = $_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] + ($_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'] * 0.90);
```

**file3.php**

```
echo $_GLOBAL_VARIABLE['cntr1'];
```

All three files (except init.php) will called randomly without ant relation and init will called once.

I dont want to try database transaction coz counter manuplation is very frequent, and file i/o is one and the same. I am looking for some way to store my data on server till the time its up and running, somewhat like global class and variables in c#.

Comment: you should try to use session or cookies

Comment: Its not client related, so its no sense to use cookies or session, which are diff for each user, where i want user centerlized counter.

Comment: Php doesn't provide support for this (sadly).
You could use memcache for it.

Comment: then you have to maintain class object which will share values on all page or need to pass varible evary time either via get or post

Comment: text file, database, memcache something like that php doesn't have application global memory space or parameters unlike .net+iis and tbh it really really needs it was one of the main things i missed switching from .net

Comment: Disk IO on a unix machine is minimal you'd have no impact just updating a text file every time apart from conflicts of file locks on a heavy usage system.  It does sound like memcached is going to be the best fit for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the store globally accessible value in the server without the use of database, cookie or session then [`memcache`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) could be a solution for you. Its a daemon which allows you to store data and use it across different connection requests. If you have frequent visits you will have to somehow handle concurrency within you application.

Comment: session and cookies won't work as they're specific to the user he wants something thats global across all user instances of the application. memcache will work though!

Comment: Note that memcache serializes the objects, so it's not really in memory storage like .NET/IIS has.

Comment: Should still be fine for just holding a counter variable/object :) this question has now reminded me of just how bad php can be

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine.

In PHP i see myself doing things in such a complicated way that could be done so much easier.

Storing compiled xslt templates in memory is impossible... (just an example)

Comment: What cracks me up is PHPOO :) really OO in an in order processed language?..... extra code + complexity very few benefits. So much better in .net where you think of it as an application not a series of web pages to be loaded one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think  this will work

```
global $cntr1;
```

If not then you can make one `.inc.php` and include this file to all pages. 
This will resolve your issue.

Comment: no it won't its specific to the user instance of the application

Comment: This answer will not satisfy the requirements of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

im sure this is NOT what you wanted, but i've used fileread/filewrite to store my globals in a file on the drive, which can be read from, written to with updated values etc. This allows for you to set MANY global variables as int's, I've modified my globals code to work as a iterator, counting up or counting down by what ever value you pass.

its a simple quick class i made to handle the request :

```
<?php
  class my_global{

    protected $name;
    protected $value;

    static protected $path = './globals/'; 

    public function __construct()
    {
      if(!is_dir(self::$path))
        mkdir(self::$path);  

    }

    public function change($name, $value)
    {           
      $current = $this->get($name); 
      $this->set($name,$current+$value);       
      return $current+$value;
    }     
    protected function set($name, $value)
    {
      $this->name = $name;    
      $this->value = $value;    
      $this->write(); 
    }
    protected function get($name)    
    {

      if(file_exists(self::$path.$name))
      {
        $myFile = self::$path.$name;
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
        $value = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
        fclose($fh); 
      }
      else
        $value = 0;

      $this->name = $name;
      $this->value  = $value;

      return $value;

    }
    protected function write(){     

      $myFile = self::$path.$this->name;
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
      fwrite($fh, $this->value);      
      fclose($fh);

    }

  }
  $my_global = new my_global();   
?>
```

You can then just call the $my_global->change() method to increase or decrease the counter

```
<?php     
  echo $my_global->change('new_global',5).'<br>';
  echo $my_global->change('anotherglobal',-2).'<br>';
  echo $my_global->change('forme',7).'<br>';
?>
```

this is more food for thought than anything, but could be used tweaked to work as you need it.